# Discrepancies between response time in server logs and chrome developer tools

Tags: performance, nginx, tornado, timing

I was load testing a site and noticed a fairly big difference between the timing information I received from the web server (in this case, a [tornado web server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)) and Chrome Developer Tools. The web server provides a service running as a process (actually, a couple of processes managed by supervisor) behind nginx. There is also a web interface to interact with this service. This tornado web server retrieves queries fairly fast (30ms on average). However, Chrome Developer Tools shows a much slower response time (around 240ms).

Every query retrieves some information and needs to query additional resources (mainly, images). I thought that was the main reason for such a big difference, but I tried using curl and `time_starttransfer` measures 172ms.

On the other hand, using this logging directive for nginx:

```
log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';
```

I was able to check that `request_time` and `upstream_response_time` are actually quite small (45 ms).

What could be the cause for such a discrepancy in response times?

**UPDATE**

This is a screenshot from Firebug:

[image]

I don't think I can figure out latency with that limited information.

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to get better information with curl. I'm not sure if it is accurate, though:

```
    time_namelookup:  0.000
       time_connect:  0.062
    time_appconnect:  0.000
   time_pretransfer:  0.062
      time_redirect:  0.000
 time_starttransfer:  0.172
                    ----------
         time_total:  0.240
```

From what I can see, `time_starttransfer - time_pretransfer = content_generation`, so 0.172 - 0.062  = 0.110s. However, looking at the logs, the web server reports 0.044s and `request_time` from nginx agrees (0.045s). Furthermore, `time_connect` in the curl output, which I think is supposed to be the latency, is not so large (0.062s).

The interesting thing is that `time_starttransfer - time_connect*2 = 0.048` is similar to the time reported by nginx or tornado (0.048 vs 0.044). But this calculation is not supposed to be correct. Does anyone know what is the correct way to justify the difference between response times in chrome developer tools/curl vs web server/nginx?

Comment: Developer tools also include latency in response time but server logs don't. Find out latency between client and server and then cross-check the values.

Comment: Interesting. How should I measure latency? ping?

Comment: ping should give you near to actual numbers as it uses smtp and not http.  I think browsers plugins like firebug or yslow can give you latency numbers.

Comment: Great. I will check firebug. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Firebug offers a "Waiting" time that includes time sending request from client to server + time for the request to be processed by the server. I don't think I can confirm the measurements for the server with that information. Yslow for some reason is not working properly as a Firefox plugin.

Comment: I updated my question with more information. Maybe that helps to figure this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL; DR

You are comparing apples with oranges...  Check your RTD with `ping`.

## HTTP request procesing

The simplified (yet still pretty complex) set of steps that occur for a single HTTP(S) request are as follows:

1. The client does a DNS lookup to resolve the host name in the URL.
2. The client establishes a TCP connection to the host server.
3. The client optionally goes through a TLS negotiation (for HTTPS connections only).
4. The client finally sends the request across the connection - the start of this stage is when the client is about to send the first byte.
5. The web server receives the request and starts processing it.
6. The web server starts sending the response.
7. The client starts receiving it - i.e. it recieves the first byte of the response.
8. The server continues to stream the data to the server until it reaches the end of the response.
9. The client receives the last of the data.

As you can see, the web server is only really aware of steps 5 to 8 (as a lot of the initial connection setup will be outside of its control) and can only measure 5-6 and 5-8.  However, the client is aware of steps 1 to 9.  In addition, it can measure the exact opposite list of data points.

## Network latency

Any request or response has to be transmitted across the network (usually the Internet for a public service) and so incurs a  delay as the data is transmitted from machine to machine.  The shortest time this can take between 2 machines (from one to the other and back again) is called the **Round Trip Time (RTT)** or **Round Trip Delay (RTD)**.  This affects all communications and is usually measured using tools like `ping`.

This RTD affects all communications and HTTP requests are no exception, so it will be very close to the sum of the delays between steps 4-5 and 6-7 in the above steps.

## Net result

Putting that all together, then, you should find that `curl` has measured steps 1-4 (well, to the start of 4) for you as returned by `time_pretransfer`.  In addition, it has also measured 1-7 (likewise the start of 7) for you as `time_starttransfer`.  The server, however, has measured the time for 5-6.

You are missing the time between 4-5 and 6-7, which we have seen above is basically the RTD.

You should therefore find that `time_starttransfer = time_pretransfer + request_time + RTD`

Comment: Thank you. I understand your point. Basically, I forgot to include RTD  in my calculation. By the way, the steps you outlined do not match exactly  the variables that curl is measuring. For example, `time_pretransfer` refers to the time "it took from the start until the file transfer was just about to begin" (previous to the web server processing the request) and `time_starttransfer` refers to the time "it took from the start until the first byte was just about to be transferred" (after the web server generated a response.), not exactly what steps 1-4 and 1-7 mean.

Comment: (cont) Another question: I thought that `time_pretransfer` and `time_starttransfer` included RTT, but your calculation doesn't support that idea. Is this correct? Is there something in curl that can be used as an approximation of RTT?

Comment: Sorry - I have over simplified.  I have clarified key timings as per [the curl docs](https://github.com/curl/curl/tree/732983eb415ca204672d7f84162dda916ccf9535/docs/libcurl/opts).  In answer to your question,  it is impossible to calculate the RTD without cooperation from the server, which is how `ping` does it.  I'm therefore unaware of (and would be surprised if there were) any curl option to do so.

Comment: No problem. I think I'm misunderstanding the definition of `time_pretransfer`. I interpreted that "... until the file transfer was just about to begin"  in the `time_pretransfer` definition refers to the moment just before the server begins to receive a request and "... until the first byte was just about to be transferred" in the `time_starttransfer` definition means the moment after the server begins to send a response. That idea was reinforced by this [explanation](http://blog.kenweiner.com/2014/11/http-request-timings-with-curl.html) and its graphical representation.

Comment: (cont) However, if I use that interpretation, there is no need to add RTD times because `time_pretransfer` should include the latency from client to server and `time_starttransfer` should not include the latency from server to client. That's the part that is very confusing.

Comment: Looks like that blog is wrong...  The [curl docs](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/732983eb415ca204672d7f84162dda916ccf9535/docs/libcurl/opts/CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME.3) are very clear that pretransfer is the time _before_ curl sends any data.  Likewise for starttransfer.

Comment: Do you mean this part "CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME \- get the time until the file transfer start"? I think it is more clear in the `time_starttransfer` [file](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/732983eb415ca204672d7f84162dda916ccf9535/docs/libcurl/opts/CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME.3): "Pass a pointer to a double to receive the time, in seconds, it took from the start until the first byte is received by libcurl." and since libcurl must be in the client, then your explanation fits perfectly.

Comment: I meant "It does __not__ involve the sending of the protocol-
specific request that triggers a transfer." in pretransfer.  You got the key bit from starttransfer - no further explanation needed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: I will wait a bit in case anyone else has something to add. Then I will select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

A client doesn't know what happens on the server. It doesn't know when the request reaches other end, and when other end started sending response.

You are trying to compare number measured from two endpoints, but there're significant delay between them and they are limited in communication.

If you really want to understand this delay in details, you should learn how TCP works. I just note that the connection action isn't something immediate, or one action, it involves exchanging packets between server and client. The same is true about transferring data.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is more a general comment than an answer. Notice that the latest update to my question deals exclusively with measurements on the server side.